# Prove or give a counterexample (assume all matrices are nxn): If AB = BC and B is nonsingular, then A = C

Tags: matrices, proof-explanation

I know that if B is nonsingular then it is invertible, but multiplying each side by B^-1 won't help because

ABB^-1 = BCB^-1 => AI = BCB^-1 => A = BCB^-1 Similarly, B^-1AB = B^-1BC => B^-1AB = IC => B^-1AB = C

I'm kind of stuck. I don't just want to guess at counterexamples and hope I'm right, I want to actually understand the solution.

Comment: You'll quickly find an example if you use some random invertible B and random A & C. Transformation $B^{-1}AB$ the standard transformation of A by the change of coordinates specified by matrix B.

Comment: Do you know how to write the linear map $T(x,y) = (x,2y)$ as a matrix with respect to the ordered basis $(1,0), (0,1)$?  What about with respect to the ordered basis $(0,1), (1,0)$?

Comment: If $B$ is singular then :
$$\exists X \neq 0, B X = 0$$
So you have a counter-example :
$$B X = 0 = B \, 0$$
and $X \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is true for all 1x1 matrices because they are multiplied same as numbers, and therefore commute. For $n>1$,
here is a counterexample.
Let
$$
B = \left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right) 
\qquad\qquad
C = \left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{array}\right)
$$
Then
$$
BCB^{-1} =
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
=  \left(\begin{array}{rr}
4 & 2 \\
3 & 1
\end{array}\right) \neq C
.$$

As others correctly noted in the comments, if $B$ is non-singular and $C$ is a matrix of a linear map in some basis, then $B$ can be thought of as a transition-to-a-new-basis matrix. It would be naive to hope that matrix of a linear map is the same in every basis.

If you're not yet familiar with linear maps and bases, here's another intuitive explanation. If $BC = CB$, then this is true because $A=BCB^{-1}=CBB^{-1}=CI=C$. But matrices don't commute in general, so this would be too much to ask.